# Best way to groupby in pandas with multiple columns and multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, summarization

I am trying to summarize a dataset on multiple columns & with multiple conditions. The dataset is transaction-level sales data and I am looking to create features like the last 3/6/9/12 Months sales, transactions, etc. I know how to do it in SQL using case when condition like "sum(case when sale_month between A to B then sales else 0 end) as sales_period", but not able to figure out a good way in python. One way I tried doing it was creating a function that returns all the values after applying conditions like below -

```
def my_agg92(x):
   names = {
       net_sales: x[sales].sum(),
       net_sales_A: x[x[A] == 'a'][sales].sum(),
       net_sales_B: x[x[B] == 'b'][sales].sum(),
       cnt_txn: x[(x[sales_month]>=X) & (x[sales_month]<=Y) & (x[type_txn] == Z)][txn_id].nunique()}
   return pd.Series(names, index = [net_sales,net_sales_A,net_sales_B,cnt_txn])
```

Then I apply this to groupby as below -

```py
summ_data = data.groupby("groupby_id").apply(my_agg92).reset_index()
```

This way its taking a lot of time to run and I am sure there exists a better way. Can someone please help with this?

[Sample Input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TtgP.png)

Desired output -

| cust_id | sale_202010_12 | sale_202101_03 | pur_txn_202010_12 | pur_txn_202101_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 590.00 | 700.00 | 2 | 1 |
| B | -50.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: please add sample input/output dataframes.

Comment: Have added both input and output dataframe. Thanks!